# SQL Adding # Prefix

Tags: sql, sorting, row-number

I have a select query that looks like

```
Type         Cause          Impact
Enhancement  Data Transfer  Cosmetic
Enhancement  Data Transfer  User Engagement
Enhancement  Front End      Cosmetic
Enhancement  Front End      User Engagement
Question     Data Transfer  Cosmetic
Question     Front End      User Engagement
Issue        Data Transfer  Cosmetic
Issue        Front End      User Engagement
```

I need the select query to turn into like this

```
Type           Cause            Impact
1.Enhancement  1.Data Transfer  11.Cosmetic
1.Enhancement  2.Data Transfer  12.User Engagement
1.Enhancement  3.Front End      13.Cosmetic
1.Enhancement  4.Front End      14.User Engagement
2.Issue        1.Data Transfer  21.Cosmetic
2.Issue        2.Front End      22.User Engagement
3.Question     1.Data Transfer  31.Cosmetic
3.Question     2.Front End      32.User Engagement
```

Essentially first column has same prefix # every unique values, and second column has increment of # and reset every first column's value has changed. Third column is just a combined of first column with second columns. Value increase based on alphabetic ascending.

I'm thinking it has to do with row number and partition by

Comment: What's the sorting order of the rows? Is there a key you are not showing?

Comment: the default sort. the # of prefix on enhancement issue and question can be any #. I just need it like format. I thought about selecting first row with using dense_rank the n do a join with row_number partition by type

Comment: See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bbcd95/27/0

Comment: ya exactly and maybe get ride of the prefix # in first 2 columns also a query that works with 2008 sql :/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select (dense_rank() over (order by type) || '.' || type) as ntype,
       (row_number() over (partition by type order by cause, impact)) || '.' || cause as ncause,
       (dense_rank() over (order by type) || row_number() over (partition by type order by cause, impact)) || '.' ||  impact) as nimpact
from t
order by ntype, ncause, nimpact;
```

Comment: the syntax || is for newer sql? i use 2008 r2. see below my answer, but wondering if there are easier query.

Comment: @DavidChen . . . `||` is the SQL standard operator for string concatenation.  Your question does not have a tag for the database being used, so this uses standard syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer but anything more simple?

```
Select t1.Type,t1.Cause,Cast(t2.rnType as VARCHAR(9))+Cast(t3.rnCause as VARCHAR(9))+'.'+t1.Impact,t1.Tickets FROM
(SELECT [Type] as Type,(Case WHEN [Cause]='' THEN 'null' ELSE [Cause] END) as Cause,(Case WHEN [Impact]='' THEN 'null' ELSE [Impact] END) as Impact,count([Id]) as Tickets FROM {SupportTicket}
GROUP BY [Type],(Case WHEN [Cause]='' THEN 'null' ELSE [Cause] END),(Case WHEN [Impact]='' THEN 'null' ELSE [Impact] END)) t1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT [Type] as Type,dense_rank() over (ORDER By [Type]) as rnType FROM {SupportTicket}
GROUP BY [Type]) t2
ON t1.Type=t2.Type
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT [Type] as Type,[Cause] as Cause,dense_rank() over (PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER By [Cause]) as rnCause FROM {SupportTicket}
GROUP BY [Type],[Cause]) t3
ON t1.Type=t3.Type and t1.Cause=t3.Cause
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```
SELECT 
  concat(typeInc, '.', Type) as Type,
  concat(causeInc, '.', Cause) as Cause,
  concat(typeInc, causeInc, '.', Impact) as Impact
FROM (
  SELECT 
    TypeInc = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Type),
    CauseInc = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Cause),
    *
  FROM tbl
  ) withInc
 ORDER by Type, Cause, Impact;
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bbcd95/27/0

---

SQL 2008 compatible version

```
SELECT 
  typeInc + '.' + Type as Type,
  causeInc + '.' + Cause as Cause,
  typeInc + causeInc + '.' + Impact as Impact
FROM (
  SELECT 
    TypeInc = CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Type) AS varchar(3)),
    CauseInc = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Cause) AS varchar(3)),
    *
  FROM tbl
  ) withInc
 ORDER by Type, Cause, Impact;
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bbcd95/29/0

Comment: Ya unfortunately my company is using sql 2008 :/

Comment: just use `+` instead of `concat` to *add* the strings (*and cast the ranking numbers as `varchars*). ***updated answer***